# Why is the plot changing when I change the range?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

`cdf[s_] := Piecewise[{{1 - (10/s), s > 10}}]
Plot[cdf[s], {s, 0, 20}]`

And it plots correctly.
[correct graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo6o6.png)

When I modify the range to, say
`Plot[cdf[s], {s, 0, 200}]`

It plots incorrectly.
[incorrect graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGalS.png)

Is this expected behavior? Am I misunderstanding something?

I played around with different ranges. The graph presents correctly up to around 180, then it starts displaying incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plot changes because the `PlotRange` changes. 
Try to add, e.g., `PlotRange -> All`

See the documentation at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html

Comment: Why does changing the plot range make it print an incorrect plot?

Comment: @Rob The question is what you define as *incorrect*. Both plot are correct only that the one with `s` from `0` to `200` shows `y` values from `0.36` to `0.98`, while the first plot shows `y` from `0` to `0.52`. The implicit option of `PlotRange -> Automatic` can sometimes clip data that you actually consider important, while the algorithm deciding on what to show obviously does not. As far as I can see, that is the only problem here.

Comment: ok that strikes me as unusual that the default setting would result in graphs that look like this. so when in doubt, set `PlotRange -> All`? Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @Rob `All` might be a problem when the data is actually diverging. Also have a look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127438/7608). If you actually know what to expect---and in your example case you do---you are better off by explicitly giving the range as in `PlotRange->{ Automatic, { 0, 1.1 } }`. Most of the time `x`, but not always, can stay `Automatic`. Cheers.